# Facebook app failing to redirect to redirect_uri

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have been working on FB app`s .all of a sudden all my app are failing . The behavior has been really weird, after the user authorizes my app, Facebook is not redirecting to destination url(redirect_uri),instead it is appended "*=*" to the URL by returning Facebook->getuser() as zero .

any immediate help would be appreciated,thanks in advance .

Comment: @danish :you can get my files from this link http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?91ti970zvn5tpco

Comment: @danishhashmi: i have used latest FB php sdk for this

Comment: i don't see the part where you are sending the redirect url along with the types of permission you want when a user first opens your app.
like if the user is visiting for the first time
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id="93829832"&
    redirect_uri="http://localhost/POST-HIT!/process.php"&
    client_secret=" "&
    code=""

Comment: @danish : in index.php,i`m constructing  login url ,for which i`m using  home_url from config_fb.php, if u see check in index.php u can see that redirect_uri=home_url.

Comment: what my whole logic is that in home_url i have "index_fb.php", so when user is redirected to this page, i check the value ($facebook->getuser()) is true or not, based on which i proceed further or redirect to index.php again ... so in my case, after succesfull login to FB, its not redirecting to that index_fb.php,and even this value ($facebook->getuser()) is zero .

Answer (score 0):

```
try {

    // check if facebook can get user
    $facebookUser = $facebook->getUser();


} catch (Exception $e) {
    // user is not logged in
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: :there is no exception raised , at the same time  the value "$facebookUser " is Zero. but app successfully logged into Facebook,not redirect to proper redirect_uri,instead appending "_=_" to the URL

Comment: Don't use try-catch block here but check whether $facebook->getUser() returns something larger than 0. If it's not, that means the user isn't logged in.

Comment: @Licson my app is successfully logging in to facebook,but the thing Fecebook php sdk is not returning the "SignedRequest" properly. because i debugged my code, i got to know that the signedRequest which should be there in the cookie is blank, due to which its returning null when we call "getUser()" funtion.I guess that would give more info on whats happening. any immediate help would be appreciated